# Is this ideal radical?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals, radicals

> Is $\left<(X+1)^4 + 4X^4\right>$ radical in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$?

I'm not even sure where to start here. I know that an ideal $I$ is radical if $I = \sqrt{I}$, but is there a nice way of showing this? I feel like I'm missing something!

Comment: A principal ideal in a UFD is radical if and only if its generator is square-free. Now, a polynomial in $k [X]$, where $\operatorname{char}k=0$, is square-free if and only if...

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Sorry, I've never heard of what you're discussing, maybe I haven't studied it yet! Is there a more rudimentary way?

Comment: I think this is as rudimental as it gets.

Comment: Modulo perhaps substituting $k\to \Bbb Q$ and $UFD\to \Bbb Q[X]$. But the ingredients are basically the same: you should be looking for an explicit criterion that allows you to tell if a polynomial is square-free.

Comment: Along the lines of the comments above you may want to check this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/936899/radical-ideals-of-mathbbz?rq=1 , where the results explained above are explained for $\mathbb{Z}$.